# HighCharts: Labels visible over tooltip frame

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I set the tooltip z-index and the labels z-index so the labels won't go over the tooltip.

```
 .label { z-index: 1!important;}

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:#ffF;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index:9999!important;
}

.tooltip {
    padding:0px;
}
```

It works for the tooltip but not for the tooltip frame.

Is there a way to fix it for the tooltip frame? Or is there a way to remove this frame?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxuhq/1/

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, the reason is that labels are using HTML tags, and border is attached to SVG element. HTML tags are always above SVG, so nothing can be done in that way.

How to solve this? Two options:

1) Remove useHTML: true for dataLabels

2) If you need to HTML tags for dataLabels, disable default border in tooltip, and create your own border in CSS for tooltip. Of course you need in that case write your own formatter for tooltip.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I can't seem to make it work with this solution. Look at that jsFiddle, the datalabel is still on top of the tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/jrqv00u4/

Comment: Remove `.highcharts-data-labels { z-index: 1 !important; }` :) Or set higher z-index for `.highcharts-tooltip` (it doesn't have any, so data labels are always rendered on top).

Comment: Best answer! Long time to find it. Saved me a lot of time (especial part about `HTML tags are always above SVG`).

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
tooltip: {
    percentageDecimals: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false
},
```

Seems there was more options than you actually needed if I read correctly that you wanted to remove the thick black border...

Hope that helps.